# TypeError: cannot append a non-category item to a CategoricalIndex

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, merge, categorical-data

I cannot merge dataframes and cannot understand why:

Simple dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': np.random.randint(1,5,100),
                    'c': np.random.random(100),
                    's': np.random.random(100)})
```

grouped to 3 groupes

```
grouped = pd.qcut(df1.c, 3)
df_grouped = df1.groupby([grouped, 'id'])
df_cross = df_grouped['s'].sum()
df_unstacked = df_cross.unstack(level=0)
df_unstacked
```

Out:

```
c   [0.018, 0.372]  (0.372, 0.771]  (0.771, 0.995]
id          
1   3.081537    6.329819    3.386422
2   4.270542    2.553301    3.778536
3   3.125476    2.525016    3.013912
4   5.762223    3.763183    7.953551
```

Second simple dataframe:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'one': range(5),
                   'two': np.random.randint(1,5,5),
                   'three': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b']})

   one three two
0   0   a   4
1   1   a   2
2   2   a   1
3   3   b   2
4   4   b   2
```

Trying to merge both:

```
pd.merge(df_unstacked, df2, left_index=True, right_on='one')
```

I would expect:

```
c   [0.018, 0.372]  (0.372, 0.771]  (0.771, 0.995]  one three   two
id                      
1   3.081537    6.329819    3.386422    1   a   2
2   4.270542    2.553301    3.778536    2   a   1
3   3.125476    2.525016    3.013912    3   b   2
4   5.762223    3.763183    7.953551    4   b   2
```

But I get TypeError:

> TypeError: cannot append a non-category item to a CategoricalIndex

Also, trying to reset_index() on df_unstacked, gives TypeError:

> TypeError: cannot insert an item into a CategoricalIndex that is not already an existing category

Making a .copy() does not help :) what to do?

p.s. pandas 0.17.1

**Update:**
As of 2023, none of these errors show up. Column index becomes non-categorical after merge. Pandas 1.4.4

Comment: your `df_unstacked` columns are categorical how do you expect this to look after the `concat`? this is where the error arises

Comment: Thanx EdChum, now I understand the problem at least :)

Comment: I'm not sure you can get around this to be honest unless you overwrite the columns with perhaps a str representation and then merge

Comment: You are right EdChum: df_unstacked.columns = df_unstacked.columns.astype(str) does the trick

Answer (score 6):

One way to make this work is to switch the order of the left and right tables.  Pandas allows you to join the Categorical columns to non-Categorical ones, but not the other way around.

```
pd.merge(df2,df_unstacked, right_index=True, left_on='one')
```

Comment: left_on = index_column_name

Answer (score 0):

The operations performed caused the column labels of `df_unstacked` to be `CategoricalIndex`; while `df2.columns` is a simple `Index`. During the merging operation, the two column labels will also be merged (resulting in an `Index` anyway). I guess that the implementation does not address this scenario where the first column labels can be an `CategoricalIndex`.

If you don't want to invert the order of the merge I suggest changing the `CategoricalIndex` into `Index`:

```py
df_unstacked.columns = df_unstacked.columns.to_list()
pd.merge(df_unstacked, df2, left_index=True, right_on='one')
```